# how to assign role to the pporal user in commerce b2b cloud

Tags: apex, screen-flow, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, flowscreen

```
public without sharing class CreateAccountContactUser{
    @InvocableMethod(label='Create_Con_User' description='Contact User')
    public static void processRecords(List<FlowInput> inputs) {
        Set<Id> orderIdSet=new Set<Id>();
        String accountId;
        String contactId;
        Set<Id> orderIdSet1=new Set<Id>();
        for (FlowInput input : inputs)
        {
           
            accountId=input.AccountId;
            contactId=input.contactId;
        }
       
        UserCreation1(orderIdSet,accountId,contactId);   
       
    }
   
   
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void UserCreation1(Set<Id> recordId,String accountId,String contactId)
       
    {
        System.debug('@@@UserCreation1Entry');
        System.debug('@@recordId' + recordId);
       
        Contact con = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone, FirstName, LastName,AccountId,Account.Owner.UserRole.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId];
        System.debug('@@@con' + con);
       
        Profile profle = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name ='Customer Community Plus User' LIMIT 1];//'Customer Community Plus User'
        System.debug('@@@profle' + profle);
       
   
       
        List<User> userList = new List<User>();
        if (contactId != null) {
           
            User u = new User();
            u.UserName = con.Email;
            u.FirstName = '';
            u.LastName = con.LastName;
            u.ContactId = con.Id;
            u.Email = con.Email;
            u.ContactId=contactId;
            u.CommunityNickname = con.LastName + '_' + Math.random();
            u.ProfileId = profle.Id;
            u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
            u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
            u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
            u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Panama';
            u.IsActive = true;
           
            if (con.LastName.length() >= 8) {
                u.Alias = con.LastName.substring(0, 7);
            } else {
                u.Alias = con.LastName;
            }
           
            userList.add(u);
           
   
            insert userList;
           
    }
       
        }
    public static void permissionInsert(List<user>userList){
       
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> uList = [SELECT Id, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.ProfileId, PermissionSet.Profile.Name,
                                               AssigneeId, Assignee.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment
                                               WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'Commerce_user'];
                                                                                                                                                   
        List<PermissionSetAssignment>permissionsetList=new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
        PermissionSetAssignment psa =new PermissionSetAssignment();
        psa.PermissionSetId=uList[0].PermissionSetId;
        psa.AssigneeId = userList[0].Id;
        permissionSetList.add(psa);
       
        insert permissionSetList;

    }
    public class FlowInput {
        @InvocableVariable
        public String recordId;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String AccountId;
        @InvocableVariable
        public String contactId;
       
    }
}
```

1. How to solve this error?

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION, Cannot create users or roles in
> an account owned by a portal user: []

2. How to create user without the profile 'system administrator' for the Owner of the account ?
3. How to assign role to portal user?

***NOTE:   I am already creating the account and contact using flow***